# shell : parse file and tell if pattern exist or not

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to make a pretty simple script which parse a file and then tell me if the string i'm looking for exists. 
I can read the txt file line by line and then use a `grep`. But I can't test if the string does not exists and I don't know why.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.txt | grep '<span>my name is john</span>' -i | while IFS= read line ; do


if test -z "$line" 
then
      echo "\$line is empty"  <--- Can't get here

else
      echo "\$line is NOT empty"
fi

done
```

Comment: grep will only return the lines that match the pattern - you're iterating over these lines - so either there are no matches or there are 1 or more - so in your code your test will always go into the line not empty - as it is only iterating matches i.e the lines that contain the string in your grep

Comment: you probably want something like: 
`if cat somefile | grep somestring -ne ""; then echo "found"; else echo "not found"; fi`

Comment: @developer that's useless use of cat, grep can read files on its own

Comment: yes, i know - i took it from their code - so as not to confuse them - good comment - very productive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to see which lines do and which don't -

```
while read line     # simplistic - see other posts on handling with more finesse
do case "$line" in  # replaces grep
   *"$yourString"*) echo "found" ;;
                 *) echo "none"  ;;
   esac
done < file.txt     # no need for cat
```

Alternately,

```
grep -i '<span>my name is john</span>' file.txt
```

gives you all the hits, and

```
grep -iv '<span>my name is john</span>' file.txt
```

gives you all the non-hits. Otherwise, you should probably put more info in your output for it to be useful.

Comment: Addendum - unless you absolutely know with zero doubt that the format of your HTML (etc) is *exactly* this, and will never change, or at least will last longer than your need for this bit of code, don't parse HTML (etc) with a regex, especially one this simple.